# How to limit response length with http.request in Node.js

Tags: node.js, http

So in this (simplified) bit of code, when someone hits my node server I make a GET request to another website and print the HTML page title to the console. Works fine:

```
var http = require("http");
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var port = 8081;
s = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
var opts = {
    method: 'GET',
    port: 80,
    hostname: "pwoing.com",
    path: "/"
};
http.request(opts, function(response) {
    console.log("Content-length: ", response.headers['content-length']);
    var str = '';
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        str += chunk;
    });
    response.on('end', function() {
        dom = cheerio.load(str);
        var title = dom('title');
        console.log("PAGE TITLE: ",title.html());
    });
}).end();
res.end("Done.");
}).listen(port, '127.0.0.1');
```

However, in the actual app, users can specify a URL to hit. That means my node server could be downloading 20GB movie files or whatever. Not good. The content-length header is no use for stopping this either as it isn't transmitted by all servers. The question then:

**How can I tell it to stop the GET request after, say, the first 10KB are received?**

Cheers!

Comment: How about checking the content-type/mime-type?

Comment: Could do I suppose, but like content-length, it's not a reliable indicator - the server I'm making a request to could still send any length of data technically. ...as I understand it anyway! Surely there must be a way of just "hanging up" after the first 10K of body.

Comment: Another approach that you might want to consider is to use streams and pipe them back to the client as they come so that you don't buffer the entire response. http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/advanced/streams/how-to-use-stream-pipe

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could abort the request once you have read enough data:

```
  http.request(opts, function(response) {
    var request = this;
    console.log("Content-length: ", response.headers['content-length']);
    var str = '';
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
      str += chunk;
      if (str.length > 10000)
      {
        request.abort();
      }
    });
    response.on('end', function() {
      console.log('done', str.length);
      ...
    });
  }).end();
```

This will abort the request at *around* 10.000 bytes, since the data arrives in chunks of various sizes.

Comment: Aha! That's what I needed. Much appreciated :)

Comment: Can you please clear me one thing? I have checked by adding a console.log('something) just before "str += chunk", it's logging only once, but I am sure that  I am receiving multiple chunk of data so in that case it should log multiple times...

Comment: @Devasish yes, you would expect so, unless you're using the same code as my answer and the request gets aborted?