# Manage security on file upload to nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have an image upload view on my client (ember.js) that send the resized image to nodejs rest api;
it works well but it is easy for someone expert to force upload of a non-resized image;
I would like to keep the resize process on the client because this allows users to select heavy-weight images, that are resized locally and uploaded only after that, when they are lightweight;

If someone else uses something like this, I'm interested on how it is possible to make this as safe as possible;

Answer (score 2):

As a rule of thumb when developing web applications is never ever trust any data coming from the client side, always try to do a check in your server side!

1. Use authentication, this ensures that user only allow to upload data to their own account and not fiddling others files.
2. Add a special message passing between your server and client, a simple example would be

   i. send a post API request first (that contains the image information and targeted compressed size) to your server indicating that your client is starting to compress the picture

   ii. when uploading, add a metadata to include the complete compressed image, and check the uploaded image with your server if it is within the accepted threshold, else discard it

You could enhance the security of the message passing to be more complicated!

This would be my simple security, anyone else got better solution? :)

Answer (score 1):

Approaches [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636095/how-to-limit-response-length-with-http-request-in-node-js) also work for file uploads. You can use a combination of checking:

1. content-length header and/or (i.e. req.headers['content-length'] > x)
2. reading stream size as it's being read by server. (i.e req.on('data'))

If the stream data exceeds a certain size you can respond accordingly. Check out something like [Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) for file uploads, specifically the limits section. Best approach would probably the second option.