# How to limit content length response of simplified HTTP request in node?

Tags: node.js, http, post, http-post

I would like to setup the [simplified HTTP request() client package](https://github.com/request/request) to abort the download of HTTP resources that are too big.

Let's imagine request() is setup to download an url and the resource size is 5 Gigabytes. I would like request() to stop downloading after 10MB. Usually, when request gets an answer it gets all the HTTP headers and everything behind. Once you manipulate the data, you have already all the downloaded data.

In axios, there is a parameter called maxContentLength but I can't find anything similar for request().

I must also mention, that I don't it to catch an error but only download at least the headers and the beginning of the resource.

Comment: Does this help? -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636095/how-to-limit-response-length-with-http-request-in-node-js

Comment: Thank you but I use a package called request and it is a simplified version of nodejs HTTP request. Nevertheless, your answer may be useful because if I get no answer, I will have to replace the request package with the HTTP request from node.

Comment: Are you talking abou this package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/request -- If so can't you use it exactly like the linked answer above, this request library still returns the same response object so it will have the prototype on and you can hook into it just the same right? Or does this library remove that functionality? This library just seems to make the process a little easier with some nice syntax.. at its core it's just returning a node request and response object

Comment: yes, I talk about npmjs.com/package/request. you gave me an idea. There is a method called .pipe in this package which catches the stream of incoming bytes. I know it because this is how it works in the original HTTP request. Then, I should be able to copy the logic. Normally, I should be able to count the number of bytes in this method and abort the request when there are too many of them.

Comment: Nice sounds like an idea! Let me know if it works!

Comment: @NicolasGuérinet Hey pal do you get your question solved? If so Don't forget to mark the answer accepted . :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const request = require('request');
const URL = 'http://de.releases.ubuntu.com/xenial/ubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso';
const MAX_SIZE = 10 * 1024 * 1024 // 10MB , maximum size to download
let total_bytes_read = 0;
```

> 1 - If the  response from the server is gzip-compressed , you should
>   enable gzip option.
>       https://github.com/request/request#examples   For backwards-compatibility, response compression is not supported by
>   default.    To accept gzip-compressed responses, set the gzip option
>   to true.

```
request
    .get({
        uri: URL,
        gzip: true
    })
    .on('error', function (error) {
        //TODO: error handling
        console.error('ERROR::', error);
    })
    .on('data', function (data) {
        // decompressed data 
        console.log('Decompressed  chunck Recived:' + data.length, ': Total downloaded:', total_bytes_read)
        total_bytes_read += data.length;
        if (total_bytes_read >= MAX_SIZE) {
            //TODO: handle exceeds max size event
            console.error("Request exceeds max size.");
            throw new Error('Request exceeds max size'); //stop
        }
    })
    .on('response', function (response) {
        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            //compressed data
            console.log('Compressed  chunck Recived:' + chunk.length, ': Total downloaded:', total_bytes_read)
        });
    })
    .on('end', function () {
        console.log('Request completed! Total size downloaded:', total_bytes_read)
    });
```

> **NB:**  If the server does not compress response but you still use gzip
>   option / decompress, then  the decompress chunk & the original chunk will be
>   equal.   Hence you can do the Limit check either way(from the
>   decompressed / compressed chunk)  However if response is compressed
>   you should check the size limit of the decompressed chunk
>
> 2 - if the response is not compressed you don't need gzip option to
>   decompress

```
request
    .get(URL)
    .on('error', function (error) {
        //TODO: error handling
        console.error('ERROR::', error);
    })
    .on('response', function (response) {
        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            //compressed data
            console.log('Recived chunck:' + chunk.length, ': Total downloaded:', total_bytes_read)
            total_bytes_read += chunk.length;
            if (total_bytes_read >= MAX_SIZE) {
                //TODO: handle exceeds max size event
                console.error("Request as it exceds max size:")
                throw new Error('Request as it exceds max size');
            }
            console.log("...");
        });
    })
    .on('end', function () {
        console.log('Request completed! Total size downloaded:', total_bytes_read)
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `data` event in this case of `request` package also. I tested below and it worked fine for me

```
var request = require("request");

var size = 0;
const MAX_SIZE = 200;
request
    .get('http://google.com/')
    .on('data', function(buffer){
        // decompressed data as it is received

        size += buffer.length;

        if (size > MAX_SIZE) {
            console.log("Aborting this request as it exceeds max size")
            this.abort();
        }
        console.log("data coming");

    }).on('end', function() {
        console.log('ending request')
    })
    .on('response', function (response) {
        console.log(response.statusCode) // 200
        console.log(response.headers['content-type']) // 'image/png'
        response.on('data', function (data) {
            // compressed data as it is received
            console.log('received ' + data.length + ' bytes of compressed data')
            // you can size and abort here also if you want.
        })
    });
```

There are two places where you can do the size checking, either where you get compressed data or where you get uncompressed data (based on example given at https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)

Answer (score 1):

As @Jackthomson pointed out in the answer of the first comment it can be done by using `.on(data)` If you want the headers you can take them from response and also you can check `content-length` header and not begin chunking.

From axios reference.

> // `maxContentLength` defines the max size of the http response
>   content allowed   maxContentLength: 2000,

This is how axios handles `maxContentLength`

```
var responseBuffer = [];
        stream.on('data', function handleStreamData(chunk) {
          responseBuffer.push(chunk);

          // make sure the content length is not over the maxContentLength if specified
          if (config.maxContentLength > -1 && Buffer.concat(responseBuffer).length > config.maxContentLength) {
            reject(createError('maxContentLength size of ' + config.maxContentLength + ' exceeded',
              config, null, lastRequest));
          }
        });
```

partial `request` equivalent

```
var request = require("request");

const MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH = 10000000;

var receivedLength = 0;

var req = request.get('http://de.releases.ubuntu.com/xenial/ubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso')
    .on('response', (response) => {
        if (response.headers['content-length'] && response.headers['content-length'] > MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH) {
            console.log("max content-length exceeded")
            req.abort();
        }
    })
    .on('data', (str) => {
        receivedLength += str.length;
        if (receivedLength > MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH) {
            console.log("max content-length exceeded")
            req.abort();
        }
    })
```

Comment: content-length header is the total size of the file not individual chunks. the OP  wants stop downloading after the max reached.

Comment: I agree. OP also mention axios and `maxContentLength`. Edit answer and added reference from axios